# Can't find database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I develop my app on my personal computer, then transfer it to my work computer.  The code below sets the connection string.  The paths are both correct yet I receive the error 52 when testing it on the network.

```
    Private Function getConnPath()
    Dim WhereAmI As String = Environment.UserName,
        p1 As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=",
        p2 As String,
        p3 As String = ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30",
        r As String
    If Environment.UserName = "Wayne" Then
        p2 = "E:\dbETS.MDF"
    Else
        p2 = "\\americas.com\LIB\Joshua\dbETS.MDF"
    End If
    r = p1 & p2 & p3
    Return r
End Function
```

[image]

I also tried the following connection strings which failed:
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|dbETS.MDF;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|dbETS.MDF;Database=dbETS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Comment: I'm not trying to access my database from the internet.  It's an mdf file stored on the network drive.  It's not a duplicate of that post as I'm not connecting via the internet, and my error code is completely different.

Comment: Does your work computer have access to the networl drive without the need for credentials?

Comment: According to [this SO answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142987/access-sql-server-express-localdb-from-local-area-network) localdb is not accessible over a network connection. You could use 'classic' SQL Server Express instead.

Comment: @peterG5 Does that mean that there's no way to access an mdf on a network path?  I do not want to install SQL Server or SQL Server Express.

Comment: @peterG I attempted to do that, and it didn't work.  I've revised my post to include my attempts.

Comment: Your revised attempt as per your edit appears to just be a change in the connectionstring. You need to install SQL Express on the server, and then connect to it. There's a lot of material on SO and elsewhere about how to do this. I can't fit it all into a comment!

Comment: I know how to install it, but I'd rather not.  Is there no other way?

Comment: You want a database server, you're going to have to install a database server!

Answer (score 0):

The error might occur for various reasons.But let me just point out the solutions.

1.Make sure **Sql server service** is running on the machine.

2.Make sure the connection string is correct.For local mdf files,a connection string might look something like :

```
 "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                      AttachDbFilename=c:\folder\SampleDatabase.mdf;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      Connect Timeout=30;
                      User Instance=True"
```

3.Make sure you have the permission to access the specific drive/folder

4.If your database requires password and username,make sure they are included in the connection string.

Hope this is somewhat useful :)

Comment: I'm not running SQL server on the work computer, as I'm connecting to an mdf and I have the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server installed.  The connection string works fine on my laptop, but not the network location.  I have rights to both folders.  The database does not require a username or password.

Comment: does this same connection string works on your main machine ?

Comment: I tried the connection string you posted and it doesn't work either.  My connection string works on my laptop.  But on my laptop the path is to a thumb drive, while on the work computer it's a network path.  Not sure if that would throw it off or not.

Comment: that's a problem,you should've mentioned that in your post :(

Comment: Not sure if you are trying to setup a remote connection or not...Anyway,[this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5adeef5-93e5-409c-b476-238e2f6dfcd2/how-to-connect-database-from-shared-drive-in-c?forum=csharplanguage) might be helpful

Comment: The post clearly states that both paths are correct and that one path is on the network.

Comment: Are you "Wayne" on both computers?

Comment: I am not trying to set up a remote connection.  I am not Wayne on both computers.

Comment: As per the suggestion I went to [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5adeef5-93e5-409c-b476-238e2f6dfcd2/how-to-connect-database-from-shared-drive-in-c?forum=csharplanguage) which lead to [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C), but ultimately I was unable to identify my error.